# Recursive deleting files from storage Laravel

Tags: laravel, storage

I have a need to be able to delete files from storage on laravel.
My idea is to loop through the files based on the folder name (course id) using this code:

```
$rootPath = public_path() .'/storage/' . $course_id . '/';

$files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
         new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
         \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);


foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{    
  // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
  if (!$file->isDir() === FALSE){
    // Get real and relative path for current file
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    //HERE I WANT TO DELETE THE ACTUAL FILE - BUT I CAN'T GET THE FILE NAME
    //$name  and $file are not carrying the filenames and hence I cant delete 
      the file

  }
}
```

and then I will delete each file using:  Storage::delete($file);

My issue is that my iteration is not showing the filenames within the directory and I have no idea what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over the directories and use

```
$success = Storage::cleanDirectory($directory);
```

to remove all files and directories in the specified directory.